# Once a function is bound with `bind`, its `this` cannot be modified anymore?

Tags: javascript, function, call, bind

Just playing around with JS a bit, I'm wondering why the following code outputs `"foo"` instead of `"bar"`:

```js
String.prototype.toLowerCase.bind("FOO").call("BAR")
```

In my understanding, [`.bind("FOO")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) returns a function that will have `"FOO"` for `this`, so calling `.bind("FOO")()` outputs `"foo"`.

But then, [`.call("BAR")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) calls the function with `"BAR"` for `this`, so `"bar"` should have been outputted.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `String.prototype.toLowerCase.bind("FOO")` returns the function `toLowerCase` with argument "FOO", if you execute `String.prototype.toLowerCase.bind("FOO")()` or `String.prototype.toLowerCase.bind("FOO").call()` you will get `foo` as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `.bind("FOO")` returns a function that will have `"FOO"` for `this`

Not quite. It returns a function which *binds `"FOO"` for `this` **of `toLowerCase`***. It works like this:

```
function bind(func, thisArg) {
    return function () {
        return func.call(thisArg);
    }
}
```

You can rebind the `this` of the returned function all you want, the `call` to `func` (here: `toLowerCase`) is already "hardcoded" to be `thisArg` (here: `"FOO"`).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Once a function is bound with `.bind()`, its `this` can no longer be modified. `this` is "replaced" permanently with the first parameter to `.bind()`.